# How to Install automake, autoconf, libtool, pkg-config on git bas windows 10

Tags: windows-10, git-bash, softhsm

I'm trying to install SoftHSMv2 from [here](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2).

Before SoftHSM building, I need to install GNU Autotools such as automake, autoconf, libtool and pkg-config on my git bash on windows 10. From where I will get these tools, i tried cygwin but after that I'm getting dependency errors while building SoftHSMv2